# Determine the drain current (PMOS-transistor)

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I have the following problem:

> Consider the circuit below
>
> [image]
>
> These component values are given: \$R_{G2}=1.5\text{M}\Omega\$, \$R_{G1}=1.2\text{M}\Omega\$, \$K=2.3\frac{\text{mA}}{\text{V}^2}\$,\$V_{to}=-1.8\text{V}\$, \$V_{cc}=5\text{V}\$.
>
> What is the drain current, \$i_D\$?

Okay, so my thought of solving this would be the following.

First find the voltage-drop across \$R_{G2}\$ through voltage division.

\$V_{G1}=V_{cc}\times \frac{R_{G2}}{R_{G1}+R_{G2}}=5\text{V}\times\frac{1.5\text{M}\Omega}{2.7\text{M}\Omega} =2.78\text{V}\$

I interpret this as also being the voltage at the gate of the pmos. That results in \$V_{GS}=2.78-5=-2.22\text{V}\$

And I'm stuck here. My next step would be to find \$V_{DS}\$, but I am unsure of how to do so. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well, you know Vgs voltage so you can find Id current without any problem. Yes?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Can I? We don't know the resistance of Rd, so how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: But your task is to find the Id current? So why do you bother about Rd and Vds?

Comment: Hint: Where does the K stand for?

Comment: (BTW, the decimal separator is a dot in English, not a comma like in German or Dutch)

Comment: K = Process transconductance parameter http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/A%20Mathematical%20Description%20of%20MOSFET%20Behavior.pdf

Comment: @G36, Okay, there must be something that I don't get, or that I have missed. My thought was to determine whether the transistor was in triode or saturation region, and then use some formulas involving Vds, Vgs, Vto and K to find id. But it seems like you have a (much) smarter way?

Comment: Since Rd was not given, you need to assume that the MOSFET is in the saturation region. What else you can do here?

Comment: Okay, so if I assume that the MOSFET is in saturation, then the formula for \$i_D=K*(Vgs-Vto)^2\$. Plugging in values we get: \$i_D=2,3mA/V*(-2,22V+1,8V)^2=40,6 mA\$. Is this correct?

Comment: no, this not correct answer.

Comment: Hmm, I think I messed up on my prefixes. I meant to write \$i_D=0,406mA = 0,41mA\$.

Comment: Much better this time.

Comment: Great! This drain current we just found. That current runs through resistor Rd, correct?

Comment: Yes, Id current will flow through Rd resistor. But why are you asking about this?

Comment: The next question in this problem, is to find out at what value of Rd the transistor is in the boundary between the triode and saturation region. Do you have any hints for this problem as well?

Comment: Do you know that boundary condition?  And your teacher or a book is using \$\frac{K}{2}\$ or just \$K\$ in the saturation region?

Comment: The boundary condition is: Vds = Vgs - Vto, correct? My teacher uses \$K\$ in the saturation region.

Comment: The MOS will be in saturation as long as |Vds| > ( |Vgs| - |Vt| )

Answer (score 1):

$$\  I_{D} = \frac{\textrm{Kp}}{2}(V_{GS}-V_T)^2 $$
$$\   I_D =\frac{\textrm{2.3}}{2}((-2.22V)-(1.8V))^2 = 0.203 \textrm{m} A = 203 \mu A  $$

Found this :
https://vlsitips.blogspot.com/2012/06/vlsi-physical-design.html
[image: Operation Modes for PMOS]

Comment: But we can "define" K "differently" and we can get rid of this 2 in the equation and use Id = K(Vgs - Vt)^2 instead. Also, as the author points outs, his teacher is using this equation  Id = K(Vgs - Vt)^2 for saturation.

Comment: OK. convention.

Comment: You right. I hope it's fine. You welcome